# Why the 'stop' pattern doesn't work in my sed command?

Tags: sed

I was following this sed tutorial: http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Sed.html#uh-29

And write the following command to dealing with "zen of python" motto, like：

```
sed '/Although/,/There/ s/a/A/g' zen

Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although prActicAlity beAts purity.
Errors should never pAss silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the fAce of Ambiguity, refuse the temptAtion to guess.
There should be one-- And preferAbly only one --obvious wAy to do it.
Although thAt wAy mAy not be obvious At first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better thAn never.
```

It seems that the start pattern works well but the stop pattern didn't work!

How to fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @AvinashRaj, doesn't work. I'm trying to replace a with A start with the line which contains an 'Although', stop until there is a 'There' in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your stop pattern does work. But hey, look:

```
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>>> Although <<< prActicAlity beAts purity.                       # Start
Errors should never pAss silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the fAce of Ambiguity, refuse the temptAtion to guess.
>>> There <<< should be one-- And preferAbly only one        \
   --obvious wAy to do it.                                        # Stop
>>> Although <<< thAt wAy mAy not be obvious At first unless \
   you're Dutch.                                                  # Start again!
Now is better thAn never.
```

You have another start pattern (`Although` word) the line after! So `sed` starts substituting again. That's all. Replace second `Although` with anything else in text, or choose `Although p` as start pattern, and everything works as expected.

Comment: You're genius, is there a way to open the /start/ and /stop/ flag only once?

Comment: @JXG But then you don't print last lines of file :/ (I agree it should work for editing a file in place with `-i`, though)